# Downloading large files using PHP

Tags: php, download, large-files

I am using following code to download files from some remote server using php

```
//some php page parsing code
$url  = 'http://www.domain.com/'.$fn;
$path = 'myfolder/'.$fn;
$fp = fopen($path, 'w');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
// some more code
```

but instead of downloading and saving the file in the directory it is showing the file contents (junk characters as file is zip) directly on the browser only.

I guess it might be an issue with header content, but not know exactly ...

Thanks

Comment: So , What is question here ?

Comment: Your code is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

to make curl_exec() return the data, and:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
fwrite($fp, $data);
```

to get the file actually written.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php :

**CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: TRUE** to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

So you can simply add this line before your curl_exec line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

and you will have the content in $data variable.

Comment: thanks everyone, I get it worked using your feedback, got some better understanding for curl options, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function that includes error handling.

```
// Download and save a file with curl
function curl_dl_file($url, $dest, $opts = array())
{
    // Open the local file to save. Suppress warning
    // upon failure.
    $fp = @fopen($dest, 'w+');

    if (!$fp)
    {
        $err_arr = error_get_last();
        $error = $err_arr['message'];
        return $error;
    }

    // Set up curl for the download
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    if (!$ch)
    {
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        fclose($fp);
        return $error;
    }

    $opts[CURLOPT_FILE] = $fp;

    // Set up curl options
    $failed = !curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);

    if ($failed)
    {
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
        return $error;
    }

    // Download the file
    $failed = !curl_exec($ch);

    if ($failed)
    {
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
        return $error;
    }

    // Close the curl handle.
    curl_close($ch);

    // Flush buffered data to the file
    $failed = !fflush($fp);

    if ($failed)
    {
        $err_arr = error_get_last();
        $error = $err_arr['message'];
        fclose($fp);
        return $error;
    }

    // The file has been written successfully at this point. 
    // Close the file pointer
    $failed = !fclose($fp);

    if (!$fp)
    {
        $err_arr = error_get_last();
        $error = $err_arr['message'];
        return $error;
    }
}
```